« Dont je me suis à dire » : sens ; (Molloy, Samuel Beckett)
Tiré de Molloy, Samuel Beckett

Ce n’était pas tout, car entre le bol et la soucoupe se dressait précairement une grande
tranche de pain sec, dont je me suis à dire, avec une sorte d’angoisse, Elle va tomber, elle
va tomber, comme si cela avait de l’importance, qu’elle tombât ou non.

On n'est pas sûr de quel verbe il s'agit :« Se suivre à dire », « s'être à dire » ?
Ni l'un ni l'autre n'ont de sens. On pourrait croire, en connaissant les origines anglophones de l'auteur que cette forme prendrait modèle sur l'expression fixe de modalité « to be to » (mais alors que fait ce temps du présent dans un récit au passé ? ).
Comment expliquer cette tournure, qui somme toute, ne peut pas exprimer quoi que ce soit de bien mystérieux et qui doit avoir un équivalent en langage compréhensible ?
Addition
Chose tout à fait intrigante, on trouve quelques lignes plus loin dans Molloy le passage suivant.

Quand je veux réfléchir en roulant, je perds l’équilibre et je tombe. Je parle au présent, il est si facile de parler au présent, quand il s’agit du passé. C’est le présent mythologique, n’y faites pas attention.


Une seule personne peut fermer une question ici? He is following himself saying: It will fall. He is following himself in his own head.

@Lambie Non, je crois qu'il  ne s'agit que d'un changement de façon de faire : on ne rend plus public les alias des responsables de la fermeture, et je ne vois qu'une raison pour ça, c'est bien sûr, permettre à ces responsables de fermer ce qu'ils veulent et tant qu'ils veulent sans laisser savoir qui ils sont (moins de « transparence » , comme on dit, ou bien est-ce qu'ils ont décidé devenir plus transparents ?)

@Lambie Oui, car.

@Lambie By the way, not a duplicate in least, and possibly another question with some interest.

@LPH 1. Essaie de ne pas sombrer dans la paranoïa. Il n'y a rien de caché, pas de hacker qui modifie les règles de Stack Exchange qui sont publiques et respectées ici. 2. C'est bien sur un duplicate. La réponse de None à l'autre question convient parfaitement à celle-ci et probablement à la plupart de celles que tu pourras te poser sur les tournures qui t'échappent chez Beckett.

@jlliagre bla-bla-bla… Peur de quoi ? Du croquemitaine ? Non ce n'est pas un « duplicate ». Elles vous échappent aussi, sinon on aurait vos réponses.

@LPH je ne vois qu'une raison pour ça, c'est bien sûr, permettre à ces responsables de fermer ce qu'ils veulent et tant qu'ils veulent sans laisser savoir qui ils sont. Non, il n'y a personne de tapi dans l'ombre. J'ai voté seul pour la fermeture de cette question et ça a suffi. Si tu n'es pas d'accord et c'est ton droit le plus absolu, tu peux voter pour la rouvrir.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Je ne vois aucun rapport entre la présente question et celle que censément elle duplique. Encore moins en quoi la réponse de @None résout quoi que ce soit des problèmes posés.

@FrançoisJurain C'est le style volontairement adopté par Beckett qui a engendré la question du PO. On ne peut pas « comprendre » Becket en passant par les canaux traditionnels de la syntaxe, de la grammaire, de l'emploi des mots. C'est au lecteur individuel de participer à une lecture active.  On ne traduit pas Beckett en « langage compréhensible ». Toute interprétation ne peut être que subjective.

@None Quoi que soit l'interprétation, il y a deux sortes de langage chez Beckett, celui qui est grammatical (l'énorme majorité, heureusement) et celui qui ne l'est pas ; se poser la question, avant toute chose, si une forme est grammaticale ou non, savoir si oui ou non on peut la copier dans le langage courant, n'est pas une affaire d'interprétation.

Tu demandes : « Comment expliquer cette tournure », et bien relis la question liée: c'est  par le style de Beckett. Tu mets la phrase en ce qui est pour toi un « langage compréhensible », tu écriras un autre texte et tu ne diras pas la même chose. Beckett sans son style ce n'est plus  Beckett.

@None Je ne parle pas de réécrire Beckett, seulement de s'assurer si pour commencer ses tournures douteuses du point de vue grammatical sont normales ou non ; on peut passer ensuite à des possibilités d'interprétation (comme ici, où plusieurs interprétations ont été proposées ; le lecteur peut ensuite faire son choix parmi ceux-là, ou un autre qui sera son choix personnel ; il y aura néanmoins un choix disponible fait par des individus habitués à cette sorte de question, un guide.
